# Clarify on recursively enumerable sets

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, recursion

In a course of mathematical logic we said that if a (first order) theory $T$ has the standard model $\mathbb N$, every recursively enumerable relation on $\mathbb N$ is weakly representable in $T$.  The proof is immediate, and it doesn't explicitely involve that $T$ has the  standard model. I don't understand if that condition is only necessary because recursive functions and relations are defined on $\mathbb N$, or if there is something  deeper. Thanks for your patience

Comment: Consider, in the language of arithmetic, the theory $\{\forall x,y(x=y)\}$. What functions are weakly representable in this theory? (For a less silly example you could look at the axioms for real closed fields, and think about what o-minimality does.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I'm not sure to understand; such a theory has only a model (that interprets every term in $0$), where any predicate is either always true or always false. So because of semantic completeness any predicate is always provable or not provable: however in both cases such a predicate can't represent a function. Am I misunderstanding something?